# Good resource for learning vowel pronunciation

Tags: hebrew, torah-reading, pronunciation, aleph-bet-letters, adult-learning

In trying to improve my leyning, I'm trying to get the finer points of vowel pronunciation down.

What is a good resource to learn, e.g., the difference between a patach and chataf-patach or a chirik vs. chirik malei?

Ideally this resource would include audio and not just IPA.

Comment: +1 Also consider differences between a kubutz and a shuruk as well as kamatz and kamatz katan (for Ashkenazim).

Comment: I don't think this is what you're looking for, but I suggest Ladefoged, _A Course in Phonetics_, for information on phonetics (and some phonology). It does not focus on Hebrew specifically, and certainly not on _halacha_.

Comment: Ladefoged's book is a general book on phonetics (I used it for a linguistics course a while ago).  It's not exactly helpful unless you know exactly what you're looking for - although the IPA chart is quite good.  

There's a book in Hebrew - Em LaMikra HaShalem (if I recall correctly) that was printed by a Rav Nisan Sharoni.  I have a copy but I don't know if it's still in print or not.  From what I remember, it was pretty clear.  Look at http://www.havrutabooks.info/home/product.php?prod_id=15790&lang=2.

Comment: Try this booklet https://avrahambenyehuda.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/heichal-avodath-hashem.pdf

Comment: According to whose tradition?